# Access Oracle Apex Application Settings from PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I've created an apex application setting `FOO` with value `bar` following [these instructions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/20.2//htmdb/managing-app-settings.html#GUID-AC6C3FE4-6F61-4463-9996-BA8666048B17).

When I try to access the setting from the `SQL Workshop > SQL Commands` page I see
`Requested Application Setting #FOO# is not defined`. Here is the SQL command I am running to retrieve the value:

```
declare
    l_value varchar2(4000);
begin
    l_value := APEX_APP_SETTING.GET_VALUE( p_name => 'FOO');
    dbms_output.put_line(l_value);
end;
```

Any idea why this won't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are not executing the code from within an APEX session, you need create an APEX session or attach yourself to to an existing APEX session otherwise there is no way to know what workspace/application to get the setting from. If the code was running from within a page, then your existing code would work.

Try executing the code below, but modify your APP ID and PAGE ID to an actual app/page within your APEX application. The username does not matter.

```sql
DECLARE
    l_value   VARCHAR2 (4000);
BEGIN
    apex_session.create_session (p_app_id => 100, p_page_id => 2, p_username => 'any_username');
    l_value := APEX_APP_SETTING.GET_VALUE (p_name => 'FOO');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_value);
    apex_session.delete_session;
END;
```

If you want to try building a function to return the setting value, I would recommend building a function like this

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FN_APP_CONFIG (
    p_setting_name   APEX_190200.WWV_FLOW_APP_SETTINGS.NAME%TYPE,
    p_app_id         APEX_190200.WWV_FLOW_APP_SETTINGS.FLOW_ID%TYPE DEFAULT APEX_APPLICATION.g_flow_id)
    RETURN APEX_190200.WWV_FLOW_APP_SETTINGS.VALUE%TYPE
IS
    l_value   APEX_190200.WWV_FLOW_APP_SETTINGS.VALUE%TYPE;
BEGIN
    SELECT VALUE
      INTO l_value
      FROM APEX_190200.WWV_FLOW_APP_SETTINGS
     WHERE flow_id = p_app_id AND name = p_setting_name;

    RETURN l_value;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
    THEN
        RETURN NULL;
    WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS
    THEN
        RETURN NULL;
END;
/
```

Comment: Thank you for the input, this resolved the issue. I was hoping for a way to set/get global variables across my apex application outside of a session (in stored procedures, ORDS restful endpoints and on pages) but it does not look like there is a way to do that.

Comment: This code can exist within a stored procedure and still function properly. When calling `APEX_SESSION.CREATE_SESSION`,  it just needs to be from a schema that has access to the workspace. This can be either the schema provisioned for the workspace or a schema that has been granted **APEX_ADMINISTRATOR_ROLE**

Comment: Right, thank you that makes sense. To avoid the overhead of creating sessions whenever these configuration items get accessed I ended up creating a function that accepts a key and returns a varchar2. This should take less time to maintain on my end, hopefully it wont cause problems down the road.

Comment: Another option is to query the settings table (`APEX_190200.WWV_FLOW_APP_SETTINGS`) directly. The schema name may need to be adjusted based on the version of APEX you have installed.

Comment: Can you think of any downsides to going with this:

```
 create or replace function FN_APP_CONFIG(
         var_config_key in varchar2
     )
    return varchar2
 is
     result          varchar2(255);
 begin
 
     result := case var_config_key
         when 'FOO' then 'bar'
         -- when ... then ...
         else ''
     end;
     return result;
 end;
```

Comment: The problem with hard coding it like that is that your function could be out of sync with the actual setting values. If a setting changes, you would have to remember to update this function as well. I have added a function to the answer for you to reference.

Comment: My plan was to skip using settings altogether and just use this function. Your function is probably better since we now have the convenience of settings modification via UI. Appreciate the input, thank you again!